# Calling Java API in the iReport expression

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to attach a call to a *Java* library into the *iReport* expression.

I tried this with a very simple library returning a hello world string.

```
package utils;
public class Hello {
    public static String hello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Within *iReport*, i want to use this API. I compiled the above library into a jar file. Added the location in *Tools -> Options -> Classpath*.

then tried the following:

- Editing the expression in a a text field `new utils.Hello().hello()`
- Creating a new field and setting its type to `utils.Hello`. Then using the `field.hello()` in the expression

In both cases, it complains that it cannot resolve hello. However its in the classpath. I've also tried to right click on the report root and add `utils.Hello/utils` to the *Java* import directive. Neither of which seemed to pick up the class.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `new utils.Hello().hello()`? Are you sure that syntax can even compile in a Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your right expression might be like this:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[utils.Hello.hello()]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The working sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT DISTINCT city FROM address ORDER BY city]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[utils.Hello.hello()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

You can also add import instruction to the report. In this case the expression will be:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Hello.hello()]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The working sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ... whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <import value="utils.Hello"/>
    <title>
        <band height="41">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="188" y="11" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Hello.hello()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Note**: For both samples the *jar* file (with ***utils.Hello*** class) must be in classpath.

### [image: Setting classpath in iReport]

More info about using srciptlets you can find [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html#scriptlet).

Answer (score 0):

You field type should be String , not utils.Hello

Comment: For which option? My problem is getting a ClassNotFoundException. So it seems that my class is not getting found.